# Visual Studio Code - Why is it removing my indentation?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, indentation

I have this problem that Visual Studio Code doesn't detect indentation properly when moving around with cursor, and actually removes indentation automatically that I have manually added.

[image]

Why is it doing this? How do you configure it? Can't seem to find the setting!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe is one of your extensions, have you tried to disable some of then to see if helps ?

Comment: I just disabled all my extensions and restarted, but the problem persists.

Comment: It's a feature in VS Code itself, I think. Go to preferences and look for options related to "trim" or "whitespace".

Comment: @MattU Thank you! "Trim auto whitespace" was the setting.

Wish cursor would auto insert indentation but I can live with this.

Comment: Good to know this, thank you @MattU, I first thought in extensions because i had problems with that on the pass.